# how to decide user's timezone withount depending on javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I solved this problem using this method:

Set the php.ini timezone = UTC

and then using javascript new Date() convert that to get the clients equivalent time.

But a serious drawback of this method is that it changes if the client changes the timezone of his system or even the time of the system. 
Javascript uses the OS time and timezone which it can send to the server for calculations that too suffers from the same problem i.e the client can fool you. Meanwhile i also saw that the birthday's on facebook are not affected by our client changing the time or the timezone.

In my case i need presently the solution for displaying the birthday today. 
Due to difference in server and client timezone. The birthday changes at 5:30 in the morning as i have set UTC as timezone in php and i am located in India. I tried and pointed out the problem in that approach.

Please suggest a solution free from the bugs mentioned above.

Comment: If you read the question, you would know that that solution doesn't work and he wants another one.

Comment: @zahreelay In addition to what zebediah49 said, you can and in fact, you should, post a question even if you have solved it for the benefit of others. StackOverflow encourages you to post a question you know the answer to and then post your solution after it. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I'd suggest looking at http://momentjs.com/. It has the ability to do date math (i.e. subtract 5.5 hours). I'd also high recommend showing relative time to the user (i.e. `timeago`).

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this...

Instead of sending the absolute time of the birthday, send the *time relative to now*.

In other words, don't have your server say "the birthday is at 12:00 May 18th". Instead, have it say "the birthday is 80 hours and 20 minutes from now."

This way, it doesn't matter what time the client thinks it is; as long as their clock is ticking at a normal speed, they will see that the birthday is "today," or "in two hours," or whatever.

You'll lose a bit of precision sending the time difference across the network, but it should be around a second or less, not a big deal.

Comment: there is column that need to show the list of people having birthay today. it has to be absolute. it cannot be relative.

Comment: Yes, in your database it should be stored as an absolute time, but you should be able to send a relative time to the client based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Many websites have a "Timezone" field in the user's profile.  It's simple, but it works.

I believe facebook either has that, or works based on the user's location.

Comment: yes it would be of great help, if you can tel me how facebook does that. how can it be done based on user's location.